# Cannot see changes in innerHTML stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a *jQuery* variable `inner_data` with a div stored inside.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="mytest_class">
        <p>hello World</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code

```
inner_data=document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
$(inner_data).find('p').replaceWith('<p class="mytest_class">Welcome World</p>');
console.log(inner_data);
```

I am not getting modified value in `inner_data` when i *console*. Don't know what is happening. Once i take inner_html , i am redirected to a new page so i have to replace previous inner_data with new without accessing from DOM

Comment: where is .child1 class? see to it that find is returning something or not.

Comment: The string in `inner_data` is a value type. It's not a reference to the element in the DOM. You'll need to retrieve the `innerHTML` again after updating the DOM

Comment: Where is PHP in this code ?

Comment: @Akshaypadwal question updated

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how to retreive it from variable itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your Script like below.

```
<script>
      var inner_data=document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
      $(".mytest_class").replaceWith('<p class="mytest_class">Welcome World</p>');
      // after changing value, again get the value from html.
      var inner_data=document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
      console.log(inner_data);
</script>
```

Comment: So my logic was wrong. Inner html stored in a variable cannot be changed . We have to take again.

Answer (score 0):

**typo error**

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;

$($("#container23").find('p')).replaceWith('<p class="mytest_class">Welcome World</p>');
console.log(inner_data);
```

Comment: What do you mean by working ? I am getting the previous inner_data even after replacing.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var inner_data = $('#container');
console.log(inner_data);
inner_data.find('p').replaceWith('<p class="mytest_class">Welcome World</p>');
console.log(inner_data);
```

The `.innerHTML` is unnecessary.

Comment: No. Once i took inner_html, then i am being redirected to another page. So before going to another page i have to modify the inner html

Comment: I need to access it from the variable inner_data

Comment: try now, I think I found the problem.

Comment: still the same.